# Правильное составление запроса insert into в c#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Нужно дописать запрос insert into в c#.Есть два текст бокс и бд access.
По нажатию на кнопку должны записываться в бд
Ни как не получается...

**Помогите грамотно и правильно написать код**

Поля access

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        string klantId = nametext.Text; //textbox название рецепта
        string klantNaam = text.Text; //textbox текст рецепта



        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";


            conn.Open();
        String ticketno = klantId;
        String Purchaseprice = klantNaam;
            String my_querry = "INSERT INTO Рецепты(Название рецепта, Текст рецепта, Вид блюда) VALUES('" + ticketno + "','" + Purchaseprice + "')";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: ну так а что не работает то?

Comment: [доки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql) глядели?

Comment: Ошибка синтаксиса INSERT INTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Рецепты([Название рецепта], [Текст рецепта]) VALUES(...
```

Comment: Я был близко,спасибо